# understanding time Elelement <time></time>

Tags: html, datetime, time, semantics

I have read so many tutorials on time element but yet I don't understand it, maybe you can help me on this :) So far what I've got is that the HTML `<time>` element is not necessary for all dates and times in your document, unless you want to restyle some time contents and in such cases you can avoid using datetime attribute.

And the other purpose of using time element is when you want to make your dates and times machine readable to gain some specific benefits, then you must use time which has its own rules that if we use datetime how it should be and if we don't how the content of time element should be, is this all, or I am being wrong on some of it?

Comment: Usage: `The HTML <time> element represents a specific period in time`. So use it that way

Comment: For all times and dates? You see? That is not a clear answer.

Comment: If you want to show time and it be understand by some tools like screen readers - yes, for all. No one enforces you to use `<time>` at all, but if you want it in semantic-ui way - use it always

Comment: So why does w3.org says this:"The time element is not necessary for encoding dates or times. In the following snippet, the time is encoded using time, so that it can be restyled (e.g. using XBL2) to match local conventions, while the year is not marked up at all, since marking it up would not be particularly useful, and doing so is thus not allowed.

<p>I usually have a snack at <time>16:00</time>.</p>
<p>I've liked model trains since at least 1983.</p>"

Comment: `"That is not a clear answer"` - Your own answer is anything but clear.

Comment: I tried to answer my own question here, check that answer, I believe that is the clear and right answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've got so far and I believe this is the right answer to my question. `<time>`...`<time/>`

> Defines a human-readable date/time.

Why and when should we use them?
You should not use time element for all times and dates in you document, we have to use them for  these 2 reasons:

1. For resytling porpuses ( for example you want to put all times ( which are in 24 hour clock ) in time element to change their style like change 16:00 to 4:00pm or to 16h00 ).
2. You have a time which you want it to be machine-readable ( 2 ways for making your time element machine-readable 1.datetime attribute 2.if datetime is not present the text node of time element written in a specific way ) for the benifits which comes from being machine-readable(  what are the benifits? better search results like when you put a machine-readable time for the publication date of your post this gives ability to user who is searching for posts which blong to a specific period of time to find them better and easier, as we can see this tool on Google search engine. Giving ability to user agents offering to users ability of adding those times in their calender or other other applications, for example, like when your time is a birthday date or date of start, implementation and end of some event. When you are talking about some event which happened 200 years ago and you want to give ability to search engings that when some user searches for that event and period of time , your content which includes that time be founded as an event which is related to that time)

NOTE: Times for which cannot specific time and date be establioshed cannot be used in time element, also, times which had occured before introduction of Gregorian calendar cannot be put inside time element ( because of difficulties of conversion of those times into Gregorian calendar )

NOTE: The pubdate attribute is a boolean attribute. If specified, it indicates that the date and time given by the element is the publication date and time of the nearest ancestor article element, or, if the element has no ancestor article element, of the document as a whole.

NOTE: The datetime attribute, if present, gives the date or time being specified. Otherwise, the date or time is given by the element's contents.
NOTE If time element does not have a datetime attribute, it must not have any element descendants, and the datetime value is the element’s child text content.
having said that it is yet better to use datetime to make yout time machine-readable :)